# how to compress json files?

Tags: python, json

I am currently writing `json` files to disk using

```
print('writing to disk .... ')
f = open('mypath/myfile, 'wb')
f.write(getjsondata.read()) 
f.close()
```

Which works perfectly, except that the `json` files are very large and I would like to compress them. How can I do that automatically? What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: thanks but that is the point: do you know how to use `zlib`? that would be helpful

Comment: well that is useful! :) I would post that as an answer. something that might seem obvious to some may not be to others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a standard module for [`zlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html), which can compress and decompress data for you. You can use this immediately on your data and write (and read) a custom format, or use the module [`gzip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html), which wraps the inner workings of `zlib` to read and write gzip compatible files, while

> automatically compressing or decompressing the data so that it looks like an ordinary file object.

It thus neatly replaces the default `open` format to interact with files, and all you need is this:

```py
import gzip

print('writing to disk .... ')
with gzip.open('mypath/myfile', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(getjsondata.read())
```

(with a change in the `open` line because I highly recommend using the `with` syntax to handle file objects.)